# how to retrieve a link from a discord message?

Tags: python, discord, bots

i'm trying to create a program, which needs to read messages from a discord bot and retrieve links from these messages.

here's the code:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import builder
import bs4


def retrieve_messages(channelid):
    headers = {
        'authorization': 'NTQ5OTM4ODEzOTUxMTQ4MDQ3.YMi7CQ.fOm6F-dmPJPEW0dehLwCkB_ilBU'
    }
    r = requests.get(f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelid}/messages', headers=headers)
    jsonn = json.loads(r.text)
    for value in jsonn:
        print(value, '\n')


retrieve_messages('563699841377763348')
```

here's the output:

````
{'id': '908857015412084796', 'type': 0, 'content': '<@&624528614330859520>', 'channel_id': '5636998413777633, 2021.```\n5J53T-BKJK5-CTXBZ-JJJTJ-WW6F3```Redeem on48', 'author': {'id': '749499357761503284', 'username': 'shift', 'avatar': 'de9cd6f3224e660a4b6906a89fc2bc15/shift-code/5j53t-bkjk5-ctxbz-jjjtj-ww6f3/?utm_source', 'discriminator': '6125', 'public_flags': 0, 'bot': True}, 'attachments': [], 'embeds': [], 'mentions': []'pinned': False, 'mention_everyone': False, 'tts': Fa, 'mention_roles': ['624528614330859520'], 'pinned': False, 'mention_everyone': False, 'tts': False, 'timest}amp': '2021-11-12T23:13:18.221000+00:00', 'edited_timestamp': None, 'flags': 0, 'components': []}

{'id': '908857014430629898', 'type': 0, 'content': '', 'channel_id': '563699841377763348', 'author': {'id': 
'749499357761503284', 'username': 'shift', 'avatar': 'de9cd6f3224e660a4b6906a89fc2bc15', 'discriminator': '6125', 'public_flags': 0, 'bot': True}, 'attachments': [], 'embeds': [{'type': 'rich', 'title': '<:GoldenKey:273763771929853962> Borderlands 1: 5 gold keys', 'description': 'Platform: Universal\nExpires: 30 November, 
2021.```\n5J53T-BKJK5-CTXBZ-JJJTJ-WW6F3```Redeem on the [website](https://shift.gearboxsoftware.com/rewards) or in game.\n\n[Source](https://shift.orcicorn.com/shift-code/5j53t-bkjk5-ctxbz-jjjtj-ww6f3/?utm_source=json&utm_medium=shift&utm_campaign=automation)', 'color': 16040976}], 'mentions': [], 'mention_roles': [], 'pinned': False, 'mention_everyone': False, 'tts': False, 'timestamp': '2021-11-12T23:13:17.987000+00:00', 'edited_timestamp': None, 'flags': 1, 'components': []}
````

in the output there are 2 links, but I need to save the second link to a variable, and I'm wondering how I can do that

Answer (score 2):

This is easiest done with the response body as a text object that can be scanned with regex to find the URLs

**Solution**

The variable test_case_data is the response body in TEXT form as a string.

````python
import re
regex = r"(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])"
def find_embedded_urls(data):
    return re.finditer(regex,data)

test_case_data = """'id': '908857014430629898', 'type': 0, 'content': '', 'channel_id': '563699841377763348', 'author': {'id': 
'749499357761503284', 'username': 'shift', 'avatar': 'de9cd6f3224e660a4b6906a89fc2bc15', 'discriminator': '6125', 'public_flags': 0, 'bot': True}, 'attachments': [], 'embeds': [{'type': 'rich', 'title': '<:GoldenKey:273763771929853962> Borderlands 1: 5 gold keys', 'description': 'Platform: Universal\nExpires: 30 November, 
2021.```\n5J53T-BKJK5-CTXBZ-JJJTJ-WW6F3```Redeem on the [website](https://shift.gearboxsoftware.com/rewards) or in game.\n\n[Source](https://shift.orcicorn.com/shift-code/5j53t-bkjk5-ctxbz-jjjtj-ww6f3/?utm_source=json&utm_medium=shift&utm_campaign=automation)', 'color': 16040976}], 'mentions': [], 'mention_roles': [], 'pinned': False, 'mention_everyone': False, 'tts': False, 'timestamp': '2021-11-12T23:13:17.987000+00:00', 'edited_timestamp': None, 'flags': 1, 'components': []}"""
# test_case_data = response.text

matches = find_embedded_urls(test_case_data)
matches = [match[0] for match in matches] #convert all urls to strings
print(matches) # List of all the urls! Index for whatever one you need
````

**Output**

```
['https://shift.gearboxsoftware.com/rewards', 'https://shift.orcicorn.com/shift-code/5j53t-bkjk5-ctxbz-jjjtj-ww6f3/?utm_source=json&utm_medium=shift&utm_campaign=automation']
```

With the URLs as a list index, you can set variables by indexing the list at whatever point you need.

Comment: Make sure to enter raw string for the regex pattern (`r""`)

Comment: Good catch. Updated.